# a way to access php session data from an external javascript file using DOM

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, xhtml

I'm creating a basic web application that simulates a micro blogging site.

When the user logs on some of the account information from the MySql query result is stored in session variable to enable tracking of the user. So userID, userName, userEmail etc..

On the create post page when the user clicks submit, an externally linked javascript file begins to work, it has it's own event handlers and uses AJAX for the rest, before outputting the result to the current "create post webpage".

Obviously, when creating the post I need to store the users ID, but I can't seem to get it to pass to the AJAX.

The solution I am thinking of is to create a hidden input field, and put the users ID (numeric number) in the placeholder, then in the JS file use the DOM and call the doc.getelementby to find out what the user ID is, I can do this fine for the post Title, and post Content, but obviously want the user ID hidden, so is there a way i can keep it hidden from the user on the create post page (it currently is a php session var) and pass it to the Ajax function to create the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps your AJAX script could call a backend PHP file that accesses the session variables via $_SESSION['userName'], $_SESSION['userEmail'], etc. and does whatever you need it to do (e.g. create a post on behalf of the user).

Put another way, the PHP acts on the currently logged in user (identified by a session variable that is unaccessible to the user) and the JavaScript updates the UI based on any response you send back to it.

Comment: Unless... by externally you mean on a completely different server. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Thanks Paul. That is how i implemented previous pages. I was hoping not to have to create an additional php script just for this reason, but i am happy to if this is the best way of doing it. @Paul Calabro - No paul it's not a different server, all on the same "box". Thanks for looking at it guys.

Comment: If that's the case (on the same server), I would definitely recommend keeping anything used in the update on the backend. It's okay to have the UI say "JSmith" (maybe you pass this back via your AJAX response) to alert the user of a successful login. Just make sure the $_SESSION['username'] = jsmith is on the backend far far way from the user and is only manipulated via an assignment that only happens after a successful login. :)

Comment: HI Paul, that worked thank you. Here is what i did: on the createpost webpage i echo'd out an hidden input box with an element tag of name=$userID - i was then able to get this in the ajax script using getELementbyID and resume processing the users post. Thank you kindly for coming back at such an ungodly hour (this silly thing had be held up for ages), much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help! Just out of curiosity, why are you using the hidden input box? These can be manipulated by the user. If Sally Sue manipulates the DOM (perhaps using Firebug) and sets the username name property to TPizza and then triggers the action to submit a post, this sounds like she might be able to influence who the post is made on behalf of. Why not just use the session variable (e.g. $_SESSION['username']) in the createpost page?

Comment: Excellent point Paul, thank you for pointing out the security issue the response has given me better understanding of it now. ideally i would like to use the sessions variables to store all the user info, but how would i access the php session variables from the AJAX script?

Comment: The PHP script that your JavaScript calls in the backend just need to do a session_start() and then access the session variable via something like $_SESSION['some_variable']. It's no different than accessing the PHP file directly. $_SESSION information is stored on the server, not the client. It doesn't really matter how you access it. It's the same info.

Answer (score 0):

You could do your idea with the hidden input and just hash the user id in the hidden field. You can hash it on the server side via PHP and even post the hashed value and decrypt via PHP before saving to the database. With jQuery you can get the value of the hidden field by:

```
val userID = $('#userID').val();
```

Slightly less work than the old fashioned `document.getElementById` method.